# Redirect both stdout and stderr to a single file and keep message order

Tags: c, linux, io-redirection

I'm trying to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to a single file with a C program.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int redirectOutputs();

int main()
{
    redirectOutputs();
    printf("OUT : test\n");
    perror("ERR : test");
    printf("OUT : test 2\n");


    int t = 23;
    printf("OUT : again\n");
    perror("ERR : again");

}

int redirectOutputs()
{
    int log = open("err.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0600);
    if (log == -1)
    {
        perror("opening err.log");
        return -1;
    }
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);
    dup2(log, STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(log, STDERR_FILENO);
    close(log);
}
```

And the output file:

```
ERR : test: Success
ERR : again: Success
OUT : test
OUT : test 2
OUT : again
```

They are both redirected well, but it seems that the all `stderr` is written and then the all `stdout`.
I would like to keep the order of messages in the file.
I should have the following file:

```
OUT : test
ERR : test: Success
OUT : test 2
OUT : again
ERR : again: Success
```

Do you know what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Is your output being buffered? Try calling `fflush()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that output through `stdout` is *buffered* while `stderr` is *unbuffered*.

You either have to make `stdout` unbuffered like `stderr`, or make `stderr` buffered like `stdout`. You set buffering and mode by using [`setvbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf).

You could also call [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) on `stdout` after each output to it.

Comment: There's an interesting idea, that I'm not able to test at the moment. Will `2>&1` do the trick as OP wants?

Comment: @iehrlich Yes, having the shell redirect `stderr` to `stdout` should work fine, and would also remove some burden on the programmer since no programmatic redirection is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is *buffering*. The simplest solution is to call `fflush()` after each output. You could of course explicitly set buffering to *line buffered* with [`setvbuf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf).

---

That said, it would probably be a better idea to have an *explicit* logging interface that just optionally catches `stderr` and `stdout` as well. And a final remark, some of your `close()` calls are redundant, `dup2()` automatically closes the new fd before duplicating.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll probably use a log macro that will flush after writting on stdout